# how to define an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

i want to define an array in python . how would i do that ? do i have to use list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List is better, but you can use array like this :

```
array('l')
array('c', 'hello world')
array('u', u'hello \u2641')
array('l', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
array('d', [1.0, 2.0, 3.14])
```

More infos [there](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html)

Answer (score 5):

Normally you would use a list. If you really want an array you can import [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html):

```
import array
a = array.array('i', [5, 6]) # array of signed ints
```

If you want to work with multidimensional arrays, you could try [numpy](https://numpy.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to use an array over a list? Here is a [comparison of the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176011/python-list-vs-array-when-to-use) that clearly states the advantages of lists.

Answer (score 3):

There are several types of *arrays* in Python, if you want a classic array it would be with the array module:

```
import array
a = array.array('i', [1,2,3])
```

But you can also use tuples without needing import other modules:

```
t = (4,5,6)
```

Or lists:

```
l = [7,8,9]
```

A Tuple is more efficient in use, but it has a fixed size, while you can easily add new elements to lists:

```
>>> l.append(10)
>>> l
[7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> t[1]
5
>>> l[1]
8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need an array because you're working with other low-level constructs (such as you would in C), you can use ctypes.

```
import ctypes
UINT_ARRAY_30 = ctypes.c_uint*30 # create a type of array of uint, length 30
my_array = UINT_ARRAY_30()
my_array[0] = 1
my_array[3] == 0
```