# Python: quick way to replace all occurances of a specific word in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of words. It's pretty large (len(list) ~ 70,000).
I'm currently using this code:

```
replacement = "bla"
for word in data:
    if (word in unique_words):
        word = replacement
```

This code take a *while* to perform the operation. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: How you optimize this depends on your needs. Does data need to preserve it's order? If no, then use a set or a Counter. Do you need all the results at one time? If no, then use a generator. Can data be broken up into smaller groups? If so, then use a dict of dict or some other higher order structure, so you only work with part of the dataset at one time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `set` for `unique_words`. Sets are considerably faster than lists for determining if an item is in them (see [Python Sets vs Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831212/python-sets-vs-lists) ).

Also, it's only a stylistic issue but I think you should drop the brackets in the `if`. It looks cleaner.

Comment: Could you explain why the brackets would make the performance slower? I don't see why that would be.

Comment: They won't, but they look ugly.

Comment: Oh man... Can't believe I haven't thought of that. I'm pretty new to Python so I wasn't aware of the no-brackets-in-an-If thing. I just saw some code once (of someone who obviously made the same mistake) and figured that's the way to go. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

The code you have posted doesn't actually do any replacement. Here is a snippet that does:

```
for key,word in enumerate(data):
   if word in unique_words:
       data[key] = replacement
```

Here's a more compact way:

```
new_list = [replacement if word in unique_words else word for word in big_list]
```

I think `unique_words` is an odd name for the variable considering its use, perhaps it should be `search_list`?

*Edit*:

After your comment, perhaps this is better:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(data)
only_once = [k for k,v in c.iteritems() if v == 1]

# Now replace all occurances of these words with something else

for k, v in enumerate(data):
    if v in only_once:
        data[k] = replacement
```

Comment: My code is supposed to replace all the words that appear only once in a training set of words with a constant *replacement* in the test set of words. For that reason the *unique_word* name makes sense. Thanks for the additional suggestions!

Comment: That part you added in your edit it pretty nice. I'm gonna use it. Thanks!