# python pyinotify to monitor the specified suffix files in a dir

Tags: python, inotify, pyinotify

I want to monitor a dir , and the dir has sub dirs and in subdir there are somes files with `.md`. (maybe there are some other files, such as *.swp...)

I only want to monitor the .md files, I have read the doc, and there is only a `ExcludeFilter`, and in the issue : https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/issues/31 says, only dir can be filter but not files.

Now what I do is to filter in `process_*` functions to check the `event.name` by `fnmatch`.

So if I only want to monitor the specified suffix files, is there a better way? Thanks.

This is the main code I have written:

```
!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyinotify                                                                    
import fnmatch                                                                      

def suffix_filter(fn):                                                              
    suffixes = ["*.md", "*.markdown"]                                                                                                                
    for suffix in suffixes:                                                         
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(fn, suffix):                                             
            return False                                                            
    return True                                                                     

class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):                                         
    def process_IN_CREATE(self, event):                                             
        if not suffix_filter(event.name):                                           
            print "Creating:", event.pathname                                       

    def process_IN_DELETE(self, event):                                             
        if not suffix_filter(event.name):                                           
            print "Removing:", event.pathname                                       

    def process_IN_MODIFY(self, event):                                             
        if not suffix_filter(event.name):                                           
            print "Modifing:", event.pathname                                       

    def process_default(self, event):                                               
        print "Default:", event.pathname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you basically have the right idea, but that it could be implemented more easily.

The `ProcessEvent` class in the **pyinotify** module already has a hook you can use to filter the processing of events. It's specified via an optional `pevent` keyword argument given on the call to the constructor and is saved in the instance's `self.pevent` attribute. The default value is `None`. It's value is used in the class' `__call__()` method as shown in the following snippet from the `pyinotify.py` source file:

```
def __call__(self, event):
    stop_chaining = False
    if self.pevent is not None:
        # By default methods return None so we set as guideline
        # that methods asking for stop chaining must explicitly
        # return non None or non False values, otherwise the default
        # behavior will be to accept chain call to the corresponding
        # local method.
        stop_chaining = self.pevent(event)
    if not stop_chaining:
        return _ProcessEvent.__call__(self, event)
```

So you could use it only allow events for files with certain suffixes (aka extensions) with something like this:

```
SUFFIXES = {".md", ".markdown"}

def suffix_filter(event):
    # return True to stop processing of event (to "stop chaining")
    return os.path.splitext(event.name)[1] not in SUFFIXES

processevent = ProcessEvent(pevent=suffix_filter)
```

Comment: I had commented earlier saying I couldn't get this to work, but now I got it. You need to edit `SUFFIXES` and remove the `*` (otherwise it never matches) and call `splitext` on `fn.name`, because the `pevent` callable takes the `Event` as its parameter. +1, nicer than my solution, and I actually tried to solve this with `pevent` but couldn't get it to work for some reason.

Comment: Thank you very much, this way is so cool! There is a little error in the code. when use `suffix_filter` as callback to `pevent`, the argument of suffix_filter is an `event`, so it should be `os.path.splitext(fn.name)[1]`

Comment: Tanky, @Paulo: Thanks for pointing out the coding errors. Whenever possible I don't post untested stuff, but couldn't in this case because my OS doesn't have inotify.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing particularly wrong with your solution, but you want your inotify handler to be as fast as possible, so there are a few optimizations you can make.

You should move your match suffixes out of your function, so the compiler only builds them once:

```
EXTS = set([".md", ".markdown"])
```

I made them a set so you can do a more efficient match:

```
def suffix_filter(fn):
  ext = os.path.splitext(fn)[1]
  if ext in EXTS:
    return False
  return True
```

I'm only presuming that `os.path.splitext` and a set search are faster than an iterative `fnmatch`, but this may not be true for your really small list of extensions - you should test it.

(Note:  I've mirrored your code above where you return False when you make a match, but I'm not convinced that's what you want - it is at the very least not very clear to someone reading your code)

Comment: Tanky you. I didn't known before that `in` operation in `set` is faster than `list`, ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831212/python-sets-vs-lists . About your note: I want to filter the suffix not match the specified, so when to filter, I return True, is there any way to make it clear?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__call__` method of `ProcessEvent` to centralize the call to `suffix_filter`:

```
class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def __call__(self, event):
        if not suffix_filter(event.name):
            super(EventHandler, self).__call__(event)

    def process_IN_CREATE(self, event):
        print "Creating:", event.pathname

    def process_IN_DELETE(self, event):
        print "Removing:", event.pathname

    def process_IN_MODIFY(self, event):
        print "Modifying:", event.pathname
```