# If the set.add() function and list serve for the same purpose in Python?

Tags: list, python-2.7, set

As what mentioned in the Title, if both of them serve for the same purpose?
Most of the time i will chose to use list, and i don't know when is a better time to use set.add() function.

I try both of them and give me the exact same result...
Personally feel list is better. What do you guys think?

```
a = set()
a.add('a1')
a.add('a2')
a.add('a3')
for ele in a:
    print ele

b = []
b.append('a1')
b.append('a2')
b.append('a3')
for ele in b:
    print ele
```

Please advise...

Comment: Look up the definition of a set.

Comment: OK, Thanks @Edgar Aroutiounian for the suggestion. I found a very good thread to describe this also [add vs list thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831212/python-sets-vs-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of general data structures, a set structure tends to allow only *one* element of *each* value whereas a list may have more than one of each.

In other words, the pseudo-code `set.add(7)` executed twice results in the set containing the single element 7 (or an error if it considers adding the same element twice to be invalid).

Using a list instead of a set would result in *two* elements, both being 7.

---

For Python specifically, adding duplicates to a set is not an error but it still plainly only allows one of each:

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(1)
>>> s.add(1)
>>> s.add(2)
>>> s
set([1, 2])
```

The list on the other hand allows multiples:

```
>>> l = list()
>>> l.append(1)
>>> l.append(1)
>>> l.append(2)
>>> l
[1, 1, 2]
```

The reason why *you* didn't see a difference is simply because you added three unique items to the list and set. In that context, they act the same. Behaviour only diverges when you add duplicate items.

Comment: Thanks @paxdiablo! you explain very well in this!