# Speed up n-gram processing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a uniqueWordList with lots of words (100.000+). 
Trigrams of every one of those words are in the set allTriGrams.

I want to build a dictionary which has all the unique trigrams as keys 
and all the words which those trigrams can be matched with as values.

Example:

```
epicDict = {‘ban’:[‘banana’,’banned’],’nan’:[‘banana’]}
```

My code so far:

```
for value in allTriGrams:   
    for word in uniqueWordList:
        if value in word:
            epicDict.setdefault(value,[]).append(word)
```

My problem:
This method takes a LOT of time. Is there any way to speed up this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if uniqueWordList was a set instead, then you can do this instead:

```
if value in uniqueWordList:
    epicDict.setdefault(value,[]).append(word)
```

Check this out:
[Python Sets vs Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831212/python-sets-vs-lists)

Comment: Thanks, considerably faster!

Answer (score 0):

Among *simple* solutions, I expect this to be faster:

```
epicDict = collections.defaultdict(set)
for word in uniqueWordList:
  for trigram in [word[x:x+3] for x in range(len(word)-2)]:
    epicDict[trigram].add(word)
```