# Why is PyCharm suggesting I convert my list to a set?

Tags: python, list, optimization, set, pycharm

Having constructed the following list:

```
NO_VACANCIES = ['no vacancies', 
                'not hiring', 
                'no open positions',
                'all positions are currently filled'
                'no positions are available'
                "don't have any vacancies"
                "we don't have any jobs available"
                "we don't have any positions available"
                'no positions are currently available']
```

... PyCharm suggested that I convert it to a `set`, but gave no justification:

[image]

What might be the benefits of such a conversion?

Comment: Do you need this to be ordered? If not a `set` is a better choice. Its faster etc etc etc

Comment: It doesn't need to be ordered, no.

Comment: Please show the exact message shown by PyCharm.

Comment: It entirely depends on how you use your data structure and what operations you execute using this structure. Read [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for more information.

Comment: @VincentSavard Thanks. Its usage is described here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118594/object-oriented-web-scraping-with-python

Comment: Check this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831212/python-sets-vs-lists

Comment: Given your upper case assignment, I assume this is intended to be an immutable constant. Sets prevent you from accidentally changing the data.

Comment: Happens to me  regularly using pycharm and in many cases where I certainly do not want a set. You can disable `"Convert Collection to set"` if you want to remove the suggestions. A simple example of where it suggests a set and I definitely don't want one  `lst = [1,2,3];from random import shuffle;shuffle(lst)`

Comment: If order is not important and you have only unique items in it, I don't see a reason *why not to use* a set. Otherwise I also suggest using the settings of PyCharm as @PadraicCunningham suggests.

Answer (score 4):

The menu you show is not a suggestion; it's a tool (known as "intention action"). It gives you possibility to change this list into a set if you decide that you need a set instead of a list. It does not tell you that this list should be a set, or that a set is somehow better in general.