# How to join two lists of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, join, dict-comprehension

I have the following simple data structures:

```
teams = [ { 'league_id': 1, 'name': 'Kings' }, { 'league_id': 1, 'name': 'Sharkls' }, { 'league_id': 2, 'name': 'Reign' }, { 'league_id': 2, 'name': 'Heat' } ]
leagues = [ { 'league_id': 1, 'name': 'League 1' }, { 'league_id': 2, 'name': 'League 2' } ]
```

And I have the following `dict` comprehension:

```
league_teams = { x['league_id']: [ t['name']
    for t in teams if t['league_id'] == x ['league_id'] ]
    for x in leagues }
```

Which yields:

```
{1: ['Kings', 'Sharkls'], 2: ['Reign', 'Heat']}
```

Is there a simpler way using `itertools` or something to get that dict? This feels a little cumbersome.

Comment: Is it necessary to search in the `leagues`? Don't you want: `league_teams = { x['name']: [ t['name']
    for t in teams if t['league_id'] == x['league_id'] ]
    for x in leagues }`?

Comment: *This feels a little cumbersome*...this may be off topic on StackOverflow as we troubleshoot code that does not work. Consider posting on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Frankly, I don't see any issue with code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an adaptation of Moinuddin Quadri's O(n+m) solution that catches the "empty league" case, and which incidentally does not require any modules to be imported. The dict `output` does double-duty as his `league_ids` set,  and since it's pre-initialized, it does not need to be a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
output = { league['league_id']:[] for league in leagues }
for team in teams:
    if team['league_id'] in output:
        output[team['league_id']].append(team['name'])
print(output)
```

The output is:

> `{1: ['Kings', 'Sharkls'], 2: ['Reign', 'Heat']}`

Comment: I presume a "Sharkl" is a small Bavarian shark.

Comment: Yes it will work, but here also the complexity will be (m+(n*m)), because `if` internally iterates thorough the list in order to make a check

Comment: To avoid the `if`, could instead use `try`... `except KeyError:pass` around the `append`.   But I guess these O() calculations omit the dict key lookup too, in all cases.

Comment: Yes, that will be fine if that is what you like. But that is not as per my definition of cleaner code. I just thought to share this with you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2831242/2063361

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `itertools` here, instead [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is better choice. Complexity of your solution is O(n*m) whereas with `defaultdict`, it will be O(n+m).

You can achieve what you want like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# create set to store `league_id` in `leagues`. Set holds unique
# values and also searching in set is faster than in normal list
leagues_id = set([item['league_id'] for item in leagues])

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for item in teams:
    if item['league_id'] in leagues_id:
        my_dict[item['league_id']].append(item['name'])
```

where at the end `my_dict` will hold the value:

```
{1: ['Kings', 'Sharkls'], 2: ['Reign', 'Heat']}
```

**Edit:** In case you also want entry in `my_dict` for the `league_id` present in leagues, but not in teams, you need to explictly make entries like:

```
for leagues_id in leagues_ids:
     _ = my_dict[leagues_id]   # Will create empty list for such ids
```

Comment: Good solution, although one thing it won't do is record empty leagues (leagues that have a name and an id but for which no teams exist). The OP's code records them as empty lists associated with a league id.

Comment: I guess you would be knowing on how to modify that in my current code :)

Comment: @jez: Added an edit to the answer. If I were you, I would have do it like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Checking `t['league_id'] == x['league_id']` looks not necessary.

You can simplify with:

```
import collections

league_teams = collections.defaultdict(list)
for t in teams:
    league_teams[t['league_id']].append(t['name'])
```

If you really want `itertools` for that:

```
import itertools

league_teams = {k: [t['name'] for t in g]
                for k, g in itertools.groupby(teams, key=lambda t: t['league_id'])}
```

But it will only work if the *teams* list is sorted.