# When printing set continer in python 3, it prints it without order

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I'm just trying to learn set containers in python.
So, I created a normal set using :

```
dset = set(['a','c','z','d'])
```

but when I print it, it results :

```
{'c', 'a', 'z', 'd'}
```

shouldn't it be :

```
{'a', 'c', 'z', 'd'}
```

Can anyone explain why the output is like this? Is there any default sort mechanism for set datatype?
or is my math is weak?

Comment: sets are not ordered containers. If you want order you have to go with lists or tuples

Comment: so they'll always give this random ordered output everytime I print a newly created set? @Ev.Kounis

Comment: It could be that you get the same output if you run it over and over again but this output is not one you can count on getting.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set) is what you want. There is a module in pypi  [ordered-set](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/)

Comment: so I'll conclude that as set are unordered containers, It will randomly print the items in it. Not any logical explanation to it? am i correct? and Thanks! @Ev.Kounis

Comment: @exabytes.js - Because of their primary usage, there is no need for there to be an order and it assists performance. See [Python Sets vs Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2831212/1324033)

Comment: @Sayse yes, this helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets are not ordered, they are not ordered containers, so nothing you can do,

If you have a list and you want to use set then convert back to list in ordered way:

```
print(sorted(set(l),key=l.index))
```

So no chance of making ordered set

Btw, there is a ordered set...

[link to download file, or just copy the code in a module and import it, remember to remove the `if __name__ == '__main__'` part in the bottom](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/)

Or `pip install boltons`, then:

```
from boltons.setutils import IndexedSet
```

Then example:

```
>>> from boltons.setutils import IndexedSet
>>> x = IndexedSet(list(range(4)) + list(range(8)))
>>> x
IndexedSet([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> x - set(range(2))
IndexedSet([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> x[-1]
7
>>> fcr = IndexedSet('freecreditreport.com')
>>> ''.join(fcr[:fcr.index('.')])
'frecditpo'
```

See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set/35258869#35258869)

Or `pip install sortedcontainers`:

Once installed you can simply:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet
help(SortedSet)
```

Or install `collections_extended`

Then example:

```
>>> from collections_extended import setlist
>>> sl = setlist('abracadabra')
>>> sl
setlist(('a', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'd'))
>>> sl[3]
'c'
>>> sl[-1]
'd'
>>> 'r' in sl  # testing for inclusion is fast
True
>>> sl.index('d')  # so is finding the index of an element
4
>>> sl.insert(1, 'd')  # inserting an element already in raises a ValueError
ValueError
>>> sl.index('d')
4
```

See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set/25988702#25988702)

Answer (score 1):

From the doc (https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.