# Python - Copy missing elements from one list into another

Tags: python, list, performance, copy

I am looking for the most efficient way to update a list.

I have a variable `self.myGlobalList = []`

I also have a recursive function that on each one of its calls is going to generate a new list with coordinates.

Say in the first iteration, I obtain the following list:

```
[(1,1), (21,22), (84,6)]
```

Since `self.myGlobalList` does not contain any of those coordinates, I will append them to it:

```
for elem in generatedList:
   if elem not in self.myGlobalList:
      self.myGlobalList.append(elem);
```

Then, on the second iteration I obtain a new generated list:

```
[(1,1), (21,22), (9,18), (71, 89), (13, 21)]
```

Now my code will again go through each element of the newly generated list and check if any are missing from `self.myGlobalList`, and if yes, append them.  The result should contain the new elements:

```
[(1,1), (21,22), (84,6), (9,18), (71, 89), (13, 21)]
```

So far so good, everything works fine.

However, my lists can contain more than 500 000+ coordinates. In terms of efficiency, will this method be sufficient, and are there any suggestions you could offer in order to optimise it?

Comment: You could use a set

Comment: You _should_ use a set, unless the order of points is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make each `generated_list` into a set, and then just keep performing `union` on the set.  The repeated code should go into a loop.

```
myGlobal = set()

generated_list = [(1,1), (21,22), (84,6)]
myGlobal = myGlobal.union(set(generated_list))
print(myGlobal)

generated_list = [(1,1), (21,22), (9,18), (71, 89), (13, 21)]
myGlobal = myGlobal.union(set(generated_list))
print(myGlobal)
```

Output:

```
{(21, 22), (1, 1), (84, 6)}
{(21, 22), (71, 89), (84, 6), (9, 18), (1, 1), (13, 21)}
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands:  No -- legacy of the production code from which I adapted this.  I updated the code; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For instance you could do something like this (*toy example*):

```
iterations = [
    [(1, 1), (21, 22), (84, 6)], [(1, 1), (21, 22), (9, 18), (71, 89), (13, 21)]]

global_set = set()
global_list = []
for iteration in iterations:
    for pair in iteration:
        if pair not in global_set:
            global_list.append(pair)
            global_set.add(pair)

print(global_list)
```

**Output**

```
[(1, 1), (21, 22), (84, 6), (9, 18), (71, 89), (13, 21)]
```

**Explanation**

The expression `if pair not in global_set` is `O(1)` (that is it takes constant time to check if an element is present), in the other hand `if pair not in global_list` would take `O(n)` to check if an element is present.

**Further**

1. Python [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).
2. [List vs Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831212/python-sets-vs-lists/17945009#17945009)