# Python pair sum problem in O(n) clarification

Tags: python-3.x, list, set

Given an integer array, output all of the unique pairs that sum up to a specific value k.

Here is the standard solution, in O(n) time:

```
    if len(arr) < 2:
        return 

    seen = set()
    output = set()

    for num in arr: 

        target = k - num

        if target not in seen: 
            seen.add(num)

        else:
            output.add((min(num, target), max(num, target))) 


    return print('\n'.join(map(str, list(output))))
```

I have a few questions regarding this solution:

1) Why do we use a set to store the seen values of the array? Why not a list? Does this change anything?

2) Why the min(num, target), max(num, target)? Is this for the sake of consistent formatting or is there a deeper reason behind this? At first, I thought it would be to deal with duplicate cases such as (1,3) & (3,1), but this solution doesn't come across that I don't think?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2831242/1862861 regarding why you would use a set rather than a list. They're more efficient when checking if they already contain a value.

Answer (score 1):

1) Set is a faster way in python to check if a value exists in and not to store duplicates that not needed in this case. 
2) The reason of doing `(min(num, target), max(num, target))` is probably to add to the output set a tuple that contains both of the numbers in the order of (min, max) that it will print in the last print statement in a better format.