# Is iterating through a list faster than iterating through a set?

Tags: python, data-structures, built-in

This is maybe a dumb question, but I was just wondering, is iterating through a set as fast as iterating through a list in python if their length was `n`? I'm guessing that getting an item from a set is not the same as a list.

for example:

```
set = {1, 4, 6, 8}
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Sets vs Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831212/python-sets-vs-lists)

Comment: was going to comment the same, that is already answered somewhere

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831212/python-sets-vs-lists remember you can't have duplicate values in a set

Comment: @TenaciousB *iterating* through a set is not faster, membership testing in a set is faster.

Comment: Did you try and see? use the `timeit` module.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I re-opened, the linked duplicate doesn't address iteration speed over both the containers.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: No problem. But are you sure that this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17945009/3545273 does not address it? (No doubt that the accepted answer does not, so re-opening can make sense anyway)

Comment: @TenaciousB yes, exactly! Thank you for the link!