# Difference between Array and Sets

Tags: arrays, set

I don't understand the difference between Arrays and Sets. What is the difference between sets and arrays in python and where does numpy appear in arrays?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Sets vs Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831212/python-sets-vs-lists)

Comment: Also, does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993984/what-are-the-advantages-of-numpy-over-regular-python-lists

Comment: The difference between sets and array sis not a programming question, but a question about data structures. Also, the subject had been treated many times before, you are are expected to do some search before asking. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type