# Why doesn't this remove duplicates from my list?

Tags: python

```
class MyObject(object):

    def __init__(self, no, text):
        self.no = no
        self.text = text

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.text == other.text
        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(str(self))

my_list = {MyObject(1, 'a'), MyObject(2, 'a'), MyObject(0, 'b')}


print(my_list)
```

This still prints out 3 objects, but I want to remove one of the elements which has the same 'a'. Why doesn't it work? I defined the MyObject class for this de-duplication purpose.

Comment: What do you expect `str(self)` in `hash(str(self))` to be? Surely you meant `hash(self.text)`

Comment: That's not a `list` [btw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831212/python-sets-vs-lists)

Comment: Also, although I don’t know what you’re using it for, you should be careful of defining objects to be equal for set-making convenience when they’re not really logically equal. A dict of `{obj.text: obj}` can accomplish the same deduplicating effect more explicitly.

Comment: @Ry- I tend to disagree. Whether 2 objects are equal is completely context\domain dependant.  In most contexts I'd totally expect `obj1 == obj2` and `{obj1, obj2} == {obj1}`  to be true at the same time but I assume this is totally a philosophical discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either change the hash method's return value to `hash(self.text)`, or, you can keep its return as `hash(str(self))` and add a `__str__` method whose return value is `self.text`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t define a `__str__` or a `__repr__`, and the default repr includes the object’s id.