# How to get the first 2 letters of a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have a string

```
str1 = "TN 81 NZ 0025" 
two = first2(str1)
print(two)  # -> TN
```

How do I get the first two letters of this string? I need the `first2` function for this.

Comment: In this case `str1.split()[0]` also works, and may make more sense if you also need the other fields.

Comment: @U2EF1, no, it does... str[0] gives you the first character, you need str[:2] and split is necessary too.

Comment: @alvas `str1.split()[0]` and `str1[0]` are two very different pieces of code.

Comment: but it does the same and achieves a single element. and then you need to join then up `"".join(str1.split()[:2])` is redundant if there is not double spacing and `str[:2]` achieves the same.

Comment: @alvas Who said `str1.split()[:2]`? U2EFI said `str1.split()[0]`

Answer (score 109, accepted):

It is as simple as `string[:2]`. A *function* can be easily written to do it, if you need.

Even this, is as simple as

```
def first2(s):
    return s[:2]
```

Comment: This one is the right way to grab the first two characters.  You answered the OP just right, so upvote.  However, I would never use a function for this.  I prefer to make it explicit in the code without having to chase down functions for verification.  As in `firsttwo = somestring[:2]` in-line in the main code

Comment: I agree, in fact I wrote “A function can be easily written to do it, if you need.” It wouldn't make sense to have tons of functions like `first2`, `first3`, `first4`…

Answer (score 15):

In general, you can get the characters of a string from `i` until `j` with `string[i:j]`.

`string[:2]` is shorthand for `string[0:2]`. This works for lists as well.

[Learn about Python's slice notation at the official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Answer (score 6):

```
t = "your string"
```

Play with the first N characters of a string with

```
def firstN(s, n=2):
    return s[:n]
```

which is *by default* equivalent to

```
t[:2]
```

Answer (score 4):

Heres what the simple function would look like:

```
def firstTwo(string):
    return string[:2]
```

Answer (score 4):

In python strings are list of characters, but they are not explicitly list type, just list-like (i.e. it can be treated like a list). More formally, they're known as `sequence` (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

```
>>> a = 'foo bar'
>>> isinstance(a, list)
False
>>> isinstance(a, str)
True
```

Since strings are sequence, you can use `slicing` to access parts of the list, denoted by `list[start_index:end_index]` see [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) . For example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a[0]
1 # first element, NOT a sequence.
>>> a[0:1]
[1] # a slice from first to second, a list, i.e. a sequence.
>>> a[0:2]
[1, 2]
>>> a[:2]
[1, 2]

>>> x = "foo bar"
>>> x[0:2]
'fo'
>>> x[:2]
'fo'
```

When undefined, the slice notation takes the starting position as the 0, and end position as len(sequence).

In the olden C days, it's an array of characters, the whole issue of dynamic vs static list sounds like legend now, see [Python List vs. Array - when to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176011/python-list-vs-array-when-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

All previous examples will raise an exception in case your string is not long enough.

Another approach is to use 
`'yourstring'.ljust(100)[:100].strip()`.

This will give you first 100 chars.
You might get a shorter string in case your string last chars are spaces.

Comment: Not true: e.g. `''[:2]` just returns `''`. No exception.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: Instead of using `def` you could give a name to a `lambda` function:

```
first2 = lambda s: s[:2]
```

Comment: [Named lambdas are bad practice](/q/38381556/4518341). Use a `def` instead.