# Is there any way to set a variable to be only the first 2 characters of another variable and set it as an integer

Tags: python

```
temp = input("Please enter the tempreture. ")
temp2 = temp[0,1]
if temp[2] or temp[3] == "C" or "c":
    new = (temp2*9/5)+32
    print(temp + " converted into Farenheit is " + new + ".")
elif temp[2] or temp[3] == "F" or "f":
    print("        ")
else:
    print("You have done something wrong?")
```

This is homework and I wanted to use the input to convert the temperature. The input would be 77C or 77F. Is there any way that I can set it as 77 as an integer so I can use it in calculations?

Comment: `temp2 = temp[0:2]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: @mkrieger1: "77c" is not a number.

Comment: Well then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988835/how-to-get-the-first-2-letters-of-a-string-in-python

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement slicing to accomplish this.

First let's define our temperature

```
temp1 = '31c'
```

Then we can convert the 31 to an integer by doing the following

```
temp1 = int(temp1[:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things at play here:

- To obtain the last character of a string, use index `[-1]`, e.g.: `example_string[-1]`. Negative indices count backwards from the end. Negative indices can also be used in slices: `example_string[2:-1]`.
- To check the identity of a letter, you first convert it into lowercase and compare this result against the lowercase version of the letter.
- Changing between types is called *casting*. Casting to an `int` is done like so: `int(example_string)`. Attempting to do perform undefined casts will result in a `ValueError`.

As this is homework, I won't spoil the end result for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the last character you can use a string slice with a negative index:

```
if tempStr[-1].lower == 'c':
    tempStr = tempStr[:-1]
```

A slice is two values separated by a colon. The value before the first colon is the first character, the value after the colon is the last character (actually the character after the last character). A negative index counts backwards from the back of the string, rather than forwards from the front.

Alternatively you might want to remove the 'C' or 'F' and convert the rest.

```
tempStr=tempStr.upper();
if 'F' in tempStr.upper():
    tempStr=tempStr.upper().replace('F','')
    temp_C = int((int(tempStr)-32)*5/9)
```