# Python unpacking line of values into two arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, unpack

I'm writing a Python script reading an input file, line by line, each containing 20 values. I'm trying to store the first one in a 1D array, and the 19 others in a second array.

They have been defined as:

```
x = numpy.zeros((n_lines))
y = numpy.zeros((n_lines,19))
```

n_lines the number of lines in my input file.
and I'm reading it with

```
for i,line in enumerate(open(infile)):
    x[i],y[i] = line.split(' ')
```

But I'm encountering an `Too many values to unpack error`

I'm now doing it by storing it in one single large array and then cutting it into two in the end. I'm not using `line.split(' ')[0],line.split(' ')[1:]` as it doesn't look optimized to split twice.

Is there a neat (Pythonista) way of unpacking?

(I'm using Python 2.7 if that matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the last part right (creating one array and then slicing it), but the first part should be done using [numpy.genfromtxt()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), like this:

```
big_array = numpy.genfromtxt(infile) ## probably with more arguments
x, y = numpy.split(big_array, [1])
```

If a more efficient solution is needed, an alternative would be:

```
big_array = numpy.empty((nlines, 20))

for i,line in enumerate(open(infile)):
    big_array[i,:] = line.split()

x, y = numpy.split(big_array, [1])
```

Finally, unpacking directly from line to the former `x` and `y` arrays can be done like:

```
splitted = line.split();
x[i], y[i,:] = splitted[0], splitted[1:]
```

Comment: It's definitely quicker to code, but as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701696/python-and-memory-efficient-way-of-importing-2d-data inefficient for large scale data import.

Comment: Then you could create the big array as a whole, and then use `numpy.split()` on it as shown. Would that solve the problem?

Comment: My question maybe wasn't clear enough, I'm sure your splitting solution would work maybe even better than the one I am using now. I'm curious to know the correct way of unpacking from 20 to 1 + 19 than how to read the file or split array. Thank you for your input by the way!

Comment: Unpacking from 20 to 1 + 19 is done like this: `one, nineteen = twenty[0], twenty[1:]`. So you could do this, I think: `x[i], y[i,:] = splitted[0], splitted[1:]` since they have respectively the same shape.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it was possible to do it in one line, without storing, but maybe this is only true in Python 3+

Comment: @Learning-is-a-mess - 3.something added this feature, ```one, *nineteen = a```

Comment: @wwii: Thank you very much for adding the final word!