# Can someone consolidate the definition and the differences between a list, an array, a numpy array, a pandas dataframe , series?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I am a Python beginner and getting confused by these different forms of storing data? When should one use which. Also which of these is suitable to store a matrix (and a vector)?

Comment: In case the current answers haven't hit the spot, this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176011/python-list-vs-array-when-to-use) on the difference of lists and arrays should suffice. Regarding pandas, they are more for table, (think Excel-like) data manipulation and analysis. Additional reading [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/index.html#what-problem-does-pandas-solve), [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/index.html#library-highlights) and [here](http://www.dyinglovegrape.com/data_analysis/part2/2da2.php).

Answer (score 0):

- list - the original Python way of storing multiple values
- array - a little used Python module (let's ignore it)
- numpy array - the closest thing in Python to the arrays, matrices and vectors used in mathematics and languages like MATLAB
- dataframe, datseries - pandas structures, generally built on `numpy`, better suited for the kind of data found in tables and databases.

To be more specific, you need to give us an idea of what kinds of problems you need to solve.  What kind of data are you using, and what do you need to do with it?

`lists` can change in size, and can contain a wide mix of elements.

`numpy.array` is fixed in size, and contains a uniform type of elements. It is multidimensional, and has implemented many mathematical functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general overview (partial credit to online documentation and Mark Lutz and Wes McKinney O'Reilly books):

- **`list`**: General selection object available in Python's standard
  library. Lists are positionally ordered collections of arbitrarily
  typed objects, and have no fixed size. They are also mutable (`str`
  for example, are not).
- **`numpy.ndarray`**: Stores a collection of items of the same type. Every
  item takes up the same size block of memory (not necessarily the case
  in a `list`). How each item in the array is to be interpreted is
  specified by a separate data-type object (`dtype`, not to be confused
  with `type`). Also, differently from lists, `ndarray`s can't be have
  items appended in place (i.e. the `.append` method returns a new
  array with the appended items, differently from `list`s).
  A single `ndarray` is a vector, an `ndarray` of same-sized `ndarray`s is a 2-d array (a.k.a matrix) and so on. You can make arbitrary n-dimensional objects by nesting.
- **`pandas.Series`**: A one-dimensional array-like object containing an
  array of data (of any `dtype`) and an associated array of data
  labels, called its index. It's basically a glorified `numpy.ndarray`,
  with labels (stored inside a `Series` as an `Index` object) for each
  items and some handy extra functionality. Also, a `Series` can
  contain multiple objects of different `dtype`s (more like a `list`).
- **`pandas.DataFrame`**: A collection of multiple `Series`, forming a
  table-like object, with a lot of very handy functionality for data
  analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Lists: lists are very flexible and can hold completely heterogeneous, arbitrary data, and they can be appended to very efficiently.

Array: The array.array type, on the other hand, is just a thin wrapper on C arrays. It can hold only homogeneous data, all of the same type, and so it uses only sizeof(one object) * length bytes of memory.

Numpy arrays: However, if you want to do math on a homogeneous array of numeric data, then you're much better off using NumPy, which can automatically vectorize operations on complex multi-dimensional arrays.

Pandas: Pandas provides high level data manipulation tools built on top of NumPy. NumPy by itself is a fairly low-level tool.

Pandas provides a bunch of C or Cython optimized routines that can be faster than numpy "equivalents" (e.g. reading text). For something like a dot product, pandas DataFrames are generally going to be slower than a numpy array

FYI: Taken from different web sources