# Python - Array goes out of bounds

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, indexoutofboundsexception

Good day everyone,

today I struggled with my code for more than an hour, just to find out that Python did not give an out of bound error.
This is my summarised code:

```
array = []
n = 0
while n < 5:
    array.append(1)
    n = n + 1
print array
for i in range(0,1):
    print i-2
    print array[i-2]
```

Clearly array[i-2] is out of bound, but the code still runs. This is the output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
-2
1
```

Am I missing something, is it my PC or is it something more in depth on how arrays in Python work?

Greetings

Comment: To add some details. What is happening is that the `-2` is not trying to access the `-2` index of the list. Based on the slicing (read the duplicate I linked), you are accessing the second to last item in the list => `[1,2,3,4][-2]` will give you 3

Comment: Detail to keep in mind just for the sake of being complete. In Python an array is not necessarily a list -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176011/python-list-vs-array-when-to-use

Answer (score 4):

You can access Python lists from the end using negative numbers. In the same way `some_list[0]` gives you the first item in the list, and `some_list[1]` the second, `some_list[-1]` will give you the last element on the list, `some_list[-2]` the second to last, etc.

```
example = [1, 2, 3, 4]
example[-1] = 4
example[-2] = 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

A note to begin: take care of how you call *python lists*, because *python arrays* also exist but they are different objects.

Then you have indeed discovered a property of python list: for your convinience using negative indexes will loop from the end of the list meaning that `some_list[-1]` is equivalent to `some_list[len(some_list)-1]`.