# unable to convert python type str into a list array

Tags: python

i'm new to python, and i am developing a tool/script for ssh and sftp.  i noticed some of the code i'm using creates what i thought was a string array

```
channel_data = str()
```

to hold the console output from an ssh session. if i check "type" on channel_data it comes back as  class 'str' ,

but yet if i perform for loop to read each item in channel_data , and channel_data contains what appears to be 30 lines from an ssh console

```
for line in channel_data:
    if "my text" in line:
        found = True
```

each iteration of "line" shows a single character, as if the whole ssh console output of 30 lines of text is broken down into single character array. i do have \n within all the text.

for example channel_data would contain "Cisco Nexus Operation System (NX-OS) Software\r\nCopyright (c) 2002-2016\r\n ..... etc. etc.. ", but again would read in my for loop and print out "C" then "i" then "s" etc..

i'm trying to understand do i have a char array here or a string array here that is made up of single string characters and how to convert it into a string list based on \n within Python?

Comment: Use the split method `for line in channel_data.split('\r\n'):...`

Comment: The standard iterator on a string in Python is a character by character iterator. If you want to iterate over a string line by line you can just `split` it by whatever your `EOL` is.

Comment: Or better yet, `channel_data.splitlines()`.

Comment: A string is a sequence of characters, which you can iterate over one character at a time.

Comment: You probably also want go give this (and the linked docs) a once-over so that this seems less magical and you're not making voodoo guesses about what is or isn't a "char array" or whatnot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate a string just like a list in Python. So, yes, as expected, your *string* type `channel_data` will in fact give you every character.

Python does not have a char array. You will have a list of strings, even as a single character as each item in the list:

```
>>> type(['a', 'b'])
<type 'list'>
```

Also, just for the sake of adding some extra information for your own knowledge when it comes to usage of terminology, there *is* a difference between array and list in Python: [Python List vs. Array - when to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176011/python-list-vs-array-when-to-use)

So, what you are actually looking to do here is take the `channel_data` string and make it a *list* by calling the *split* method on it.

The `split` method will, by default, split on white space characters only. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). So, you will want to make sure what you want to actually split on and provide that detail to the method.

You can take a look at [splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) to see if that works for you.

As specified in the documentation for `splitlines`:

> Line breaks are not included in the resulting list unless keepends is
>   given and true.

Your result will then be a list of strings as you expect. So, as an example you can do:

```
your_new_list_of_str = channel_data.split('\n')
```

or

```
your_new_list_of_str = channel_data.splitlines()
```

Comment: They key thing about `splitlines` is that it handles 'universal' line endings for you. Which is something you may (e.g. reading random text file) or may not (e.g. strictly adhering to some protocol) want.

Comment: @pvg Very true, yes. I can add that detail, I decided to count on going to the doc to get that detail.

Answer (score 0):

`string_list = channel_data.splitlines()`
See docs at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines