# Is array.count() orders of magnitude slower than list.count() in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count

Currently I am playing with Python performance, trying to speed up my programs (usually those which compute heuristics). I always used lists, trying not to get into `numpy` arrays.

But recently I've heard that Python has [**`8.7. array — Efficient arrays of numeric values`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) so I thought I would try that one.

I wrote a piece of code to measure an `array.count()` vs. a `list.count()`, as I use it in many places in my code:

```
from timeit import timeit
import array

a = array.array('i', range(10000))
l = [range(10000)]


def lst():
    return l.count(0)


def arr():
    return a.count(0)


print(timeit('lst()', "from __main__ import lst", number=100000))
print(timeit('arr()', "from __main__ import arr", number=100000))
```

I was expecting a slight performance improvement when using `array`. Well, this is what happened:

```
> python main.py
0.03699162653848456
74.46420751473268
```

So, according to `timeit` the `list.count()` is 2013x faster than the `array.count()`. I definitely didn't expect that. So I've searched through SO, python docs etc. and the only thing I found was that the objects in array have to be first wrapped into `int`-s, so this could slow things down, but I was expecting this to happen when creating an `array.array`-instance, not when random accessing it (which I believe is what `.count()` does).

So where's the catch?

Am I doing something wrong?

Or maybe I shouldn't use standard arrays and go straight to `numpy.array`s?

Comment: Is that `array` from `import array` same as NumPy arrays?

Comment: No, it is not. I used two data types: standard python lists and arrays. And I asked if maybe I should use third type (for numeric values), numpy arrays

Comment: list vs array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176011/python-list-vs-array-when-to-use

Comment: array seems to occupy much less memory than lists. see https://www.dotnetperls.com/array-python

Comment: It also states, at the end of article, that arrays scale much better. On small test-cases, list can outperform array (like your case -10000). For the benchmark test on 10^7, array is the winner.

Comment: You don't create the list correct. The list just ontains one element, `range(10000)`

Comment: But then the list is still two times as fast as the array

Comment: `numpy` arrays don't have a `count` method.

Comment: But they have `==` operator and `count_nonzero()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *where's the catch?*

### The initial test, as proposed above does not compare apples to apples:

not mentioning the [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7), where **`range()`** creates indeed a RAM-allocated data-structure, whereas **`xrange()`** resembles a [python-3](/questions/tagged/python-3) re-formulated object ( as seen below ) a *generator*-will never be comparable to whatever smart RAM-allocated data-structure.

```
>>> L_above_InCACHE_computing = [ range( int( 1E24 ) ) ]    # list is created
>>> L_above_InCACHE_computing.count( 0 )                    # list has no 0 in
0
>>> L_above_InCACHE_computing.count( range( int( 1E24 ) )  )# list has this in
1
```

---

The generator's object intrinsic **`.__len__()`** spits out the length, where still no counting takes place, does it? <sub>( glad it did not, **it would not fit into even `~ 10^20 [TB]` of RAM ...**, yet it can "live" in py3+ as an object )</sub>

```
>>> print( L[0].__doc__ )
range(stop) -> range object
range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object

Return an object that produces a sequence of integers from start (inclusive)
to stop (exclusive) by step.  range(i, j) produces i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1.
start defaults to 0, and stop is omitted!  range(4) produces 0, 1, 2, 3.
These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
```

---

### Quantitatively fair testing? Better test engineering details are needed:

Go well above a few tens of MB, so as to avoid false expectations from InCACHE-computing artifacts, that will never scale-out to real-world problem sizes:

```
>>> L_above_InCACHE_computing = [ range( int( 1E24 ) ) ]
>>> L_above_InCACHE_computing[0]
range(0, 999999999999999983222784)

>>> print( L_above_InCACHE_computing[0].__len__() )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t
```

Go into RAM-feasible, yet above InCACHE-horizon sizings:

```
# L_aRunABLE_above_InCACHE_computing = [ range( int( 1E9 ) ) ] # ~8+GB ->array
# would have no sense to test 
# a benchmark on an array.array().count( something ) within an InCACHE horizon
```

---

> *go straight to **`numpy`** arrays ?*

Definitely a wise step to test either. Vectorised internalities may surprise, and often do a lot :o)

Depends a lot on your other code, if numpy-strengths may even boost some other parts of your code-base. Last but not least, beware of premature optimisations and scaling. Some **`[TIME]`**-domain traps could be coped with if can spend more in **`[SPACE]`**-domain, yet most dangerous are lost InCACHE-locality, where no tradeoffs may help. So, better do not prematurely lock on promising detail, at a cost of loosing a global scale performance target.

Comment: Jesus Christ, you're right. I did create it with list comprehension now, and you're right again, array still like 2x slower than the list: `29.802288375514255
53.67833035401182`

Comment: @Frynio Once I fix your list comprehension bug (`lst = list(range(10000))`) I also see arrays being ~2.5x slower. But as @ user3666197 points out whether or not that is a problem in your situation depends on a lot of other factors. So I'll just quote Prof. Donald Knuth: "premature optimization is the root of all evil".