# Genereating all possible combinations of array (without repetition) in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, algorithm

How would you get every possible combination of array below?

Example for `array=[1,2,3]`

Possible combinations are

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 2 1
3 1 2
```

Comment: itertools.permutations

Comment: What did you try or research for this?

Comment: Side note `array` is different than `list`.  Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176011/python-list-vs-array-when-to-use if interested to know more.

Comment: Those are permutations, not combinations.  Also, you should describe what you mean by "without repetition".  Is that a condition of your input (i.e. the list will not contain repetitions) or a filter on the output (i.e. the permutations should not have repeated values even when the list does contain duplicates) ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `itertools` module specifically the `permutation`:

```py
from itertools import permutations

print(list(permutations([1, 2, 3])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is easy because lots of library are available.
go through the documentation for source code
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

```
import itertools
a=[1,2,3]
for k in itertools.permutations(a, len(a)):
    print(k)
```

Solution

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
```